# Rails AJAX call for an action renders view twice

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a user registration form in my Rails app. I didn't use standard Rails form, but a custom HTML form. Data is passed to the `create` action in `UsersController` by an AJAX call.

This is my form:

```
<!-- Register Form -->
<div class="user_register">
 <form>
   <label><%= t(:full_name)%></label>
   <input type="text" id="name"/>
    <br />

    <label><%= t(:email_address)%></label>
    <input type="email" id="regmail"/>
    <br />

    <label><%= t(:password)%></label>
    <input type="password" id="regpassword"/>
    <br />

    <label><%= t(:password_again)%></label>
    <input type="password" id="password_confirm"/>
    <br />

    <input id="send_updates" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="send_updates">Send me occasional email updates</label>

    <div class="action_btns">
    <div class="one_half"><a href="#" class="btn back_btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> <%= t(:Back)%></a></div>
    <div class="one_half last"><a href="#" id="register_button" register_url=<%= root_url+'/create_user' %> class="btn btn_red"><%= t(:sign_up)%></a></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$( "#register_button" ).click(function() {
  var email = $('#regmail').val();
  var name = $('#name').val();
  var register_url = $('#register_button').attr('register_url');
  var password = $('#regpassword').val();
  var password_confirm = $('#password_confirm').val();

  jQuery.ajax({ 
    url: register_url, 
    type: 'POST', 
    data: {
      'user' : {
        'password': password,
        'password_confirmation': password_confirm,
        'name': name,
        'mail': email
      }
    },
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function() { window.location.reload(true); },
    beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));},                           
  });
});

</script>
```

And the code for my controller is:

```
def create
  if params[:user][:password].eql?(params[:user][:password_confirmation])
    @user = User.new({:name=>params[:user][:name], :mail=>params[:user][:mail], :username=>params[:user][:username], :hashed_password=>Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(params[:user][:password])})

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: t(:congratulations_can_now_log_in) }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: t(:error_while_registering) }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  else
    redirect_to :back, notice: t(:error_while_registering)
  end
end
```

AJAX calls the `create` action for creating a new user, and that action renders a view. If AJAX succeed, then the page is loaded again (`success: function() { window.location.reload(true); }`). So I get 2 GET calls to the same URL, the first by the action and the second by AJAX on success.

The problem is that if the first GET contains some notice or alert these can't be viewed, as the second GET, delete them (as a reload).

What I would like to do is to avoid the second GET call (reloading the page by AJAX), but when I insert an empty function or a function that do nothing in the success option, the AJAX call failed.

What could I do?

Comment: What do you mean "the ajax call failed"? Is there a Javascript error message?

Comment: Why not use the Rails form helpers with `remote: true` option to let rails perform the ajax call for you and then handle the response with `create.json.erb` or `create.js.erb` templates?

Comment: "ajax failed" means that there is no response from server, the screen remain blank